# postgresql expression wher id is in array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have an array of ids such as:

```
a = [13, 51, 99, 143, 225, 235, 873]
```

What is the most efficient way of getting the records where the id is in the array.

I don't really want to use `or` such as `WHERE id = 13 || 92` , as the array could be extremely long. I've tried this:

```
select * from authors where id <@ [11, 8, 51, 62, 7];
```

but that's not correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `any`

```
select * 
from authors 
where id = any (array[11, 8, 51, 62, 7]);
```